# Formula to determine when mean is stable

Tags: mean

I have a sample of values. Every day the sample grows because new values will be added. Every day I calculate the mean of these values. For research purposes I want to know the day that the mean starts to stabilize.

If I plot the means with on the x axis the days (dates) and on the y axis the the means I can clearly see the mean stabilizing after a couple of days. However, finding the stabilization day this way by hand (actually by eye) seems to me a little bit inaccurate.

Is there a way to calculate or a formula that helps the finding the stabilization day?

Many thanks in advance!

*Edit*

By stabalize I refer to the sample means. Ofcourse I know there will always be some fluctuation, but when I look at the plotted line it's starting to show a rather straight line after a couple of days. How do I determine by using a formula when the line is straight and horizontal?

Comment: By "stabilize" are you referring to the *sample means* or to a hypothesized mean of the *process* that generates the data?  Please note that neither is guaranteed to stabilize; there are even situations where the more data you collect, the more their mean fluctuates!  It would therefore help to know something about what these data are measuring and what you asssume about the underlying process.

Comment: I added some information :) @whuber

Comment: This sounds like it might be related to something called a Kalman filter.

Comment: Note that the line will *never* be straight and horizontal.  You have to decide when it is *horizontal enough.*  Laws of Large Numbers and various universal bounds, such as Chebyshev's Inequality, provide formulas of the type you seek.